# Retrieving variable from tuples in dataframe and code discrepancies

Tags: python, pandas

So here is a code I made for extracting the n-th element of tuples contained in a df "dataframe"  :

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]])
splitframe1=df.copy()
splitframe2=df.copy()
splitframe1.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
splitframe2.applymap(lambda x: x[1])
```

## This won't work... WHY???

While in the console it outputs:

```
   0  1
0  2  4
1  6  8
```

if I recall the splitframe2, I retrieve the original dataframe df.
On the other hand, with

```
splitframe1=dataframe.copy().applymap(lambda x: x[0])
splitframe2=dataframe.copy().applymap(lambda x: x[1])
```

It works fine, splitframe2 can be retrieved in the expected version.
May somebody explain me where's my conceptual error? I don't bet on a pandas glitch. Still, I would have expected the fact of using applymap on the copies through their respective variables to work and replace the tuples by the variables?

Comment: What won't work? applymap is not an inplace operation. `splitframe1` won't change based on that. You need to assign the result back to `splitframe1`. (i.e. `splitframe1 = splitframe1.applymap(lambda x: x[0])`)

Comment: That's a good point;) Still I am not sure it is constant behavior, I was using copies exactly because applymap operations I used did affect some dataframes while I was assigning to other dfs... Might be some mistake of mine again, anyway.

Comment: Anyway, you can write this as a solution so I accept this.

Comment: There must be something else. For this example I don't think you need copies. `splitframe1 = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])` should work fine without affecting the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `splitframe1.applymap(lambda x: x[0])` and `splitframe1=dataframe.copy().applymap(lambda x: x[0])` is that in the former you don't assign back the result. applymap returns a new dataframe; it doesn't change the original dataframe. You can assign this new dataframe back to the original one:

```
splitframe1 = splitframe1.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```